# Is it possible to create a "global" class instance in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sorry for the silly question, I'm a newbie in Unity scripting.

I need to create a class instance which it need to be shared and accessed by the components in any scene.

I could easily create a static class and use it in the component scripts, but my class have heavy network and processing, and since I need to process it only once, it would be nice to create only a single instance.

Is it possible to do something similar to that?
For example:

```cs
// The class which I need to create and share
public class DemoClass {
     MyExampleClass example;
     public DemoClass (){
            example = new MyExampleClass ();
      }
     public MyExampleClass GetClassInstance(){
            return example;
      }
 }

// The "Global Script" which I'll instantiate the class above
public class GlobalScript{
    MyExampleClass example;
    public void Start(){
         DemoClass demoClass = new DemoClass();
         example = demoClass.GetClassInstance();
     }

     public MyExampleClass getExample(){
         return example;
      }
  }

  // Script to insert in any component
  public class LoadMyClass : MonoBehaviour {
      public void Start(){
          // this is my main issue. How can I get the class Instance in the GlobalScript?
          // the command below works for Static classes.
          var a = transform.GetComponent<GlobalScript>().getExample(); 
       }
    }
```

Any hint on this would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing you're coding in C#?

Comment: @krillgar Sorry. Yes I'm coding in c#. Just added the tag.

Comment: So, if you are coding in C# - this is totally NOT a unity question. You ask something way too low level. As in: This is a purely C# question.

Comment: @TomTom This, in fact, does have to do with Unity. It cannot be described as "purely C#" when the code very much references retrieving a component's transform.

Comment: Further, Unity3D supports C# as one of it's primary programming languages. If the OP says he/she is using Unity, and a design pattern that's used in his/her's scene, then it surely is a Unity question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At a simple level, it would seem that a singleton pattern would be the way to go (as mentioned above). While not from an official Unity resource, here is a link to a tutorial and also a code example that is documented fairly well.

http://clearcutgames.net/home/?p=437

Singleton Example:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Singleton : MonoBehaviour
{
    // This field can be accesed through our singleton instance,
    // but it can't be set in the inspector, because we use lazy instantiation
    public int number;

    // Static singleton instance
    private static Singleton instance;

    // Static singleton property
    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        // Here we use the ?? operator, to return 'instance' if 'instance' does not equal null
        // otherwise we assign instance to a new component and return that
        get { return instance ?? (instance = new GameObject("Singleton").AddComponent<Singleton>()); }
    }

    // Instance method, this method can be accesed through the singleton instance
    public void DoSomeAwesomeStuff()
    {
        Debug.Log("I'm doing awesome stuff");
    }
}
```

How to use the singleton:

```
// Do awesome stuff through our singleton instance
Singleton.Instance.DoSomeAwesomeStuff();
```

Comment: Usually you want to make the constructor of your Singleton class `private` so only the `public static Singleton Instance` getter method can create a new instance.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I agree. They key word is "usually." However, using the constructor when the class inherits from MonoBehaviour, will make the constructor to be called at unwanted times and in many cases might cause Unity to crash.

Comment: My bad I should have said use `protected` not `private` you are correct private could cause it to crash.

Answer (score 2):

Read about the conveniently named [Singleton](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton). They are a pre-Unity software design pattern that addresses the need for having only one such instance. There are many Unity specific, generic examples online.

From the included link, 
""Why Singleton?", you may ask. First, then, what's a singleton? It is a design pattern that restricts the Instantiation of a class to one object. And, if you're here, you probably want to use that basically for implementing Global Variables. For any other usage, just take this as a starting place.
The advantage of using singletons, in Unity, rather than static parameters and methods, are basically:

1. Static classes are lazy-loaded when they are first referenced, but must have an empty static constructor (or one is generated for you). This means it's easier to mess up and break code if you're not careful and know what you're doing. As for using the Singleton Pattern, you automatically already do lots of neat stuff, such as creating them with a static initialization method and making them immutable.
2. Singleton can implement an interface (Static cannot). This allows you to build contracts that you can use for other Singleton objects or just any other class you want to throw around. In other words, you can have a game object with other components on it for better organization!
3. You can also inherit from base classes, which you can't do with Static classes.

For Unity specifically, there is also the added notion that said script will be assigned to a game object that normally will be destroyed on a new level load.  This is why there is usually a Unity-centric method to prevent the destruction of the gameobject when loading a new level.

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(singleton);
```

I highly recommend familiarizing yourself with design patterns in general especially related to game development.  They are fun and very powerful when applied in the right place.

Comment: Link only answers are generally frowned upon in the event the link becomes dead.  Could you please add the relevant text into the answer along with the link as well?

Comment: Yes, this solves what I'm trying to archieve. I'll dig around this.
I'm just wondering if there is a "non-hack" solution bundled in Unity.
Thanks.

Comment: If you want to burden your process with that responsibility, I think there are ways to do something similar, but I wouldn't want to suggest something that is more untested than what is included here.  For example, you can create that object in your opening scene and only call: 
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this)
But then another developer (including  yourself) could toss another of this same prefab into a scene and then what would that mean?  I firmly believe in cases like this, it is better to serve a standard that is common opposed to rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of singletons, I would like to consider just using [**ScriptableObjects**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) which are generally used to store data globally.

An example [class](https://gamedevbeginner.com/how-to-get-a-variable-from-another-script-in-unity-the-right-way/#scriptable_objects):

```
using UnityEngine;
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Float Variable")]
public class FloatVariable : ScriptableObject
{
    public float value;
}
```

You would implemently as this:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour

{
    public FloatVariable playerHealth;
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("The player's health is: " + playerHealth.value);
    }
    void TakeDamage(float damageTaken)
    {
        playerHealth.value -= damageTaken;
    }
}
```

Using the inspector you can change the value on the `ScriptableObject`, and then you can drag and drop in the ScriptComponent in the game object.