# How to keep a GameObject destroyed when switching scenes, but reseit it when Starting a New Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

(I'm new to Unity)I'm working on a Lovecraft inspired game.I have multiple game scenes apart from the main menu. I also have multiple game objects that, after the Player interacts with them, are destroyed. Some are destroyed OnTriggerExit or after an IEnumerator. I kept them destroyed when the Player switch the scenes by using a static bool. My problem is that after the objects are destroyed, and if I want to start a new game, they are kept destroyed. I don't know how to reset them. Here's an example. I made a crow that plays an animation, and after that animation is played, it is destroyed.
Here's the code

```
{
    
    public Animator anim;
    public AudioSource audioSource;
    public AudioSource Flyingsound;
    public GameObject Crow;
    public GameObject trigger;
    static bool m_IsDeleted = false;
    static bool n_IsDeleted = false;
   
    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("Flying");
            audioSource.Play();
            GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
            Flyingsound.Play();
            StartCoroutine(crow(4));
            m_IsDeleted = true;
            n_IsDeleted = true;
        }   
    }
    
   IEnumerator crow(float waitTime)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        Destroy(Crow);
        Destroy(this);  
    }
   
    public void Awake()
    {
        if (m_IsDeleted)
            Destroy(Crow);
        if(n_IsDeleted)
            Destroy(this);
    }
}
```

I tried to acces the bool in the Main Menu script and reset it to false on "Start New Game" button click, but I can't acces it due to being a static and having the "inaccessible due to protection level" error and if I set the bool to public the game object are no longer kept destroyed between scenes.
I don't know to reset those game objects when starting a new game or what's the workaround this..
The Main Menu script is:

```
public GameObject gameObject;

    public void PlayGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("p_x");
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("p_y");
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("TimeToLoad");
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("Saved");
    }

    public void QuitGame()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }

    public void ContinueGame()
    {
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LoadSaved") == 1)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SavedScene"));
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just have an initial scene which sole job is to load a global state, use the user preferences.

Steps:

1. load first scene
2. scene loads data from user preferences
3. use data from step 2 to update a global none destroyable class instance

when destroying items. just add the unique id of said object/element to the user preferences.

then when the game loads it will do the above.

when you load the game scene, just check the global class instance and if its id is there, then dont spawn it.

[Global Class Instance - source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35161273/6651840)

Comment: I wil try this. Thank you so much for answering!

Comment: Happy to help, well done, and keep at it ;)